# How to create a trigger that update the date field and time field upon modify of the row?

Tags: sql-server-2008, trigger, row-modification-time

I have created a table `testtable` inside the database `testbase` that have the following structure:

```
product_no (int, not null)
product_name (varchar(30), not null)
price (money, null)
expire_date (date, null)
expire_time (time(7), null)
```

However, how do I write a trigger such that it will update that particular row that has been modified (or updated with new information) and record the modification date into the `expire_date` field and the modification time into the `expire_time` field? (or if this is possible?)

Comment: Have you looked at how a trigger is created?

Comment: yes, I have looked at how trigger is created (Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799(v=sql.105).aspx) but one thing is bothering me is that how does one insert the UPDATE statement for the row that is being trigger by getting the condition correct as in `WHERE id = Changed_Row_ID`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It would be fairly easy but I would actually recommend changing the logic of the command that is inserting/updating the data so that it adds the additional information at this point.

However, should you wish to proceed with a trigger you could do something like this:

```
create trigger my_trigger
on my_table
after insert, update
as
begin
declare @dt datetime = getdate();
update a
set expire_date = CONVERT(DATE, @dt, 101),
    expire_time = CONVERT(TIME, @dt)
from my_table as a
join inserted as b 
on a.product_no = b.product_no; 
end
go
```

This uses the `INSERTED` table to find out the `product_no` of the rows that have been changed/created. You can find out more about triggers at the link below:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx

I hope this helps you.

Comment: I never thought that MS SQL actually will form a table called `inserted`. So, does that mean that it would be safe not to have your own database table to have name such as `inserted` and `deleted`?

Comment: Yes I would recommend not having your own tables with these names just to avoid confusion ;-)

Comment: on the create trigger manual page you can find a link  to the following page describing the use of the inserted/deleted tables (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx)